# Meant for only some people

Tags: single-word-requests

The word is used to refer to a thing  which is meant for only some people. For example: *theoretical physics is a subject that is meant only for some people*. So the word can be used here instead of "meant for only some people". (The word starts with "p" I feel").

**The original, very first version of this question:**

*A happy coincidence 
The word is used to refer to a thing which you happen to come along , you are not looking for it ...but in this case "co-incidence" doesn't seem right 'because only one event is happening which is favourable to the other event (without deliberate effort or thought),there is no "co-incidence".The events are not coincident(they don't occur at same time).*

Comment: *An acquired taste? An esoteric interest*?

Comment: Why have you edited the question?

Comment: Yes, why was the question edited? Much of the discussion below now has no connection to the current version of the question.

Comment: @AshStuart that was my revised version and not the original one.

Comment: I'm so confused...What is this question asking?  It seems to be two completely unrelated things...
In the future, do not change your question to ask something completely different - edits are for clarifying and correcting

Comment: @Doc Don't patronise me ! I believe they were two good questions, whatever you might say.

Comment: Also please make sure to clearly state what your question is.  For the 'original' question, make sure to ask "What is a better word for coincidence" if that's what you want.  For the current question, make sure to ask "What is a word that means `for only some people`?"  As written, you're just making a statement and it isn't clear what you are asking about.

Comment: @Argot The point isn't that the questions were necessarily bad, it's that they're two **different** and **unrelated** questions.  The answers below are now extremely confusing to read because you changed questions halfway through.

Comment: @doc i guess I can say the question is "esoteric" ( meant for only people with some degree of understanding ).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12691/discussion-between-doc-and-argot)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Serendipitous* is the word you want. If it's a positive/pleasant event, it is serendipity.

NOTE: The above answer was for the original question which was completely different from what I see above now. I haven't had an answer as to why the question was so drastically changed and folk downvoted my answer to the original question, but it's very discouraging.

(from the edit history):

*A happy coincidence 
The word is used to refer to a thing which you happen to come along , you are not looking for it ...but in this case "co-incidence" doesn't seem right 'because only one event is happening which is favourable to the other event (without deliberate effort or thought),there is no "co-incidence".The events are not coincident(they don't occur at same time).*

Comment: You nailed it ! Touché .(if it is my question ,then there is an argument and this point leaves no room for arguement so that is why I say "touché").

Comment: Thanks very much. This word is an old fave of mine I have used as an example of how you can get a word that means exactly what you asked today. :-) So could we say that was doubly serendipitous ;-)

Comment: I really don't see how the word *serendipitous* answers the question asked. [Serendipitous](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/serendipitous) means discovered by chance. I must be missing something.

Comment: The question has been completely edited. The original question as seen in the edit history is rather different from what I can see now.

Comment: I don't get it. I answer the question that was asked, and then someone fully edits the question to something different, and folk downvote my answer? Why?

Comment: AshStuart, Yeah that's frustrating. (I wasn't the downvoter, by the way.)

Comment: Thanks JLG, I will probably discuss - on the meta forum, how one can be allowed to fully change a question leading to such confusion as here.

Comment: You gotta love this, more folk downvoting an answer that answered a question that has morphed over time. Should we apologize for answering questions asked here?!

Comment: AshStuart: Sorry - ***I*** downvoted you a day or two ago when I hadn't realised the question at the time was totally different to the one you'd answered, but I totally forgot about it later when the mess became clear. I'm afraid OP has ruffled quite a few feathers here - if he can't/won't sort it out, perhaps we should ask a mod to split the question in two and divide the answers according to which one they're addressing. Since your text now makes it clear *which* Q you've answered, I've no hesitation in apologising and reversing my downvote.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps **[peculiar](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/peculiar)**

> Belonging distinctively or primarily to one person, group, or kind; special or unique

Or **[esoteric](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/esoteric)**

> Intended for or understood by only a particular group

Comment: Please peculiar doesn't conform , please delete it so that I could accept your answer. Esoteric is the answer ! Thank you.

Comment: Since you didn't delete peculiar , I couldn't accept ! And even decided to change my question.

Comment: I must admit when I posted *my* answer (which some idiot has seen fit to downvote), I didn't notice your second suggestion *(esoteric)*. Immediately after posting, I saw you'd given the same word as me, so I upvoted your answer - but I left mine because I thought *recondite* was also relevant to the question *as it was phrased at the time*. But looking at the question text now (it's been revised yet again), I think it's probably irretrievably flawed - so I'm closevoting as **Unclear**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yeah, the history here is a mess and I'm not sure it adds to the collective wisdom.

Comment: They say there's no such thing as a stupid question, only stupid answers. But then again they say the moon's made of green cheese...

Answer (score 2):

There is the word *exclusive* which means **limited to only one person or group of people** http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/exclusive_1?q=exclusive

Comment: This is wrong comprehension of my question , the answer was "esoteric".I know semantics !! In this case , it does not necessarily means it is "meant for only those limited people".Other people are also competent enough to be a part of that "exclusive" thing .Theortical physics is not exclusive in any se

Comment: I noticed that you have changed your question.

Comment: Your answer has a slight difference to "the answer"...exclusive is "meant for some people", not on the basis of "competences" but on basis of "prestige,premium etc.".the answer was "esoteric".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's *unique to*. When something is unique to a group of people, it is only meant for them.

Comment: Sorry,but unique is "only one"this is like "only some"